# Any way to limit a running docker container's net io

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, docker-swarm

I know we can limit cpu and memory using the command
`docker container update`, but this command has no option about network io. Is there any way to fulfill this?

Comment: no native way, see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25497523/how-can-i-rate-limit-network-traffic-on-a-docker-container

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50031926/how-to-limit-docker-images-network-usage-or-bandwidth)?